# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop, while creating a table

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React. I would like to remove this warning. I tried to explore the Web and tried  many solutions but none was working for me (key, rowkey, loop, etc.)

Error:

> Check the render method of `RankingTable`
> in tr (created by RankingTable)
> in RankingTable react_devtools_backend.js:2540:25

Do you have an idea for this issue?

```
return (
  <div className = "overflow-x-auto">
    <table className="ranking_table table-auto border-collapse w-full" >
      <caption className="sr-only">{ caption }</caption>
      <thead>
      {
        fields.map((field) => (
          <tr>
          <th>{ field.player }</th>
          <th>{ field.total }</th>
          <th>{ field.exact }</th>
          <th>{ field.good } </th>
          </tr>
        ))
      }
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {
            rows.map((row, loop) => ( 
              <tr key={row.key}>
                <td>
                  <span className={`rounded-full rank ranking-${loop + 1}`}>{ loop + 1 }</span> { row.username }, 
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    { row.cntTotal }
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    { row.cntExact }
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    { row.cntGood }
                  </td>
                </tr>
            ))
        }
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need provide keys for any elements you're mapping through like the `tr` tags in `tbody`. You'd need to do the same for `thead`

Comment: Here's the link to the official react docs for more info on why keys are required https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Ok thanks! I thought there was an issue with tbody, but issue was in thead. As there is only one result, I thought it was not necessary to add a key to thead > tr.

Answer (score 2):

Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.
Source of content https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

You have to pass unique value in key for each iteration of map. Which must not be repeat through out the loop iteration.
If there exist a unique id or any unique value in the **fields**  for each object, then you can pass it in key.

```
 <thead>
  {
    fields.map((field) => (
      <tr key={field.<id or something that is unique>}>
      <th>{ field.player }</th>
      <th>{ field.total }</th>
      <th>{ field.exact }</th>
      <th>{ field.good } </th>
      </tr>
    ))
  }
  </thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `key` in your mapping, like @Shawn Yap said. Make sure to use something unique.

> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys.

The updated `thead` should look like this:

```
   <thead>
   {
      fields.map((field) => (
         <tr key={field.<id or something that is unique>}>
            <th>{ field.player }</th>
            <th>{ field.total }</th>
            <th>{ field.exact }</th>
            <th>{ field.good } </th>
         </tr>
      ))
   }
   </thead>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was not necessary to add a key to thead, because there was only one result.